# Как определить, что интернет-магазин использует Angular и Material Design?

Tags: angular2, material-design, интернет-магазин

Заказчик просит показать ему примеры магазинов на Angular + Material Design. Как я понимаю, мне необходимо пройтись по произвольным магазинам и по определённым признакам отсеять те из них, которые работают на этой связке.

Как можно, будучи простым посетителем сайта, определить, что на нём используются  эти технологии? Было бы хорошо ещё иметь возможность узнавать, использует ли backend сайта Node.js и WebSocket.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос является оффтопиком. На сайте рассматриваются вопросы по программированию, а не собираются примеры проектов.

Comment: Вопрос связан с программированием. В другое место не знаю где искать.

Comment: Подобный неформат можно попробовать спросить в чате so.

Comment: Связан, но слишком общий. Тут вопросы по конкретным проблемам, а не по целым проектам.

Comment: Поправил вопрос. Понимаю что не правильно сформулировал. Надеюсь так не нужно его удалять :)

Comment: @other Восстановил вопрос и поправил его так, чтобы максимально подходил под формат StackOverflow. Дело в том что если закрою его то возможность задать вопросы останется заблокированным. Можете смотреть: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7188/Как-узнать-сколько-времени-действует-блокировка

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear, Этот вопрос не выправить, слишком уж не формат. Зато можно ещё минусов нахватать.

Comment: @Other Не подумал про такую ситуацию :) Может быть назначить конкурс? Хочу поправить баланс голосов, после этого могу и удалить. Такая уж система SO.

Comment: **== Комментарии выше относятся к предыдущей версии вопроса; сам вопрос впоследствии был переформулирован ==**.

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear, вопрос старый, Вы уверены что из-за него проблемы? Переформулировка от Arhad помогла, но лишь самую малость.

Comment: Нашёл ещё один вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738366/Где-можно-найти-инфо-про-feathers-js

Comment: @Other если Вы поставили минус, снимите его пожалуйста, вопрос поправили.

Comment: @ValeriuVodnicear, мои минусы, что хочу, то и делаю :) Но я не ставил.

Comment: @Other только попросил. Конечно минусы Ваши.

Comment: Достаточно просто поставить расширение в браузере wappalyzer, которое покажет использующиеся технологии на текущем сайте.

Comment: добавлю ссылку: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существуют сайты, которые автоматически выполняют работу по определению движка сайта. Вы вбиваете URL - они вам дают оценку, какой движок. Некоторые сайты понимая, что оценка вероятностная - дают несколько версий.

Как это работает? Некоторые движки можно опознать по установленным кукисам (пример: битрикс по умолчанию ставит куки `BITRIX_`, хотя именно в этом движке это можно поменять), по некоторым файлам лицензий в корне сайта, по определённым строкам в исходном коде, по расположению папок, записям в robots.txt и тому подобное.

Конкретные примеры подобных сайтов - ищите в гугле, они каждый год разные.